# iterating through fixed number of elements, at a time in an xml file. python Element tree

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am having an xml file as shown.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataRoot>
    <Data>
    <Data>
    <Data>
       <child>
          ....text....
       </child>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    <Data>
    <Data>
    <Data>
      .
      .
      .
</DataRoot>
```

My requirement is to split this xml to smaller xml files with fixed number of `<Data>` element in each file.
I am able to split at each `<Data>` to a xml , but unable to take a fixed number`<Data>` element and form the file.

my output is:
file1:

```
<DataRoot>
   <Data>
</DataRoot>
```

file2:

```
<DataRoot>
   <Data>
</DataRoot>
```

But required output is:

file1:

```
<DataRoot>
   <Data>
   <Data>
   <Data>
</DataRoot>
```

file2:

```
<DataRoot>
   <Data>
   <Data>
   <Data>
</DataRoot>
```

Here goes my code.

```
    import os
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import lxml.etree as LT

    file_path = 'filepath\\file.xml'
    file_name = (os.path.splitext((os.path.basename("%s"%file_path)))[0])
    print file_name

    tree = ET.ElementTree(file='%s'%file_path)
    tre = LT.ElementTree(file='%s'%file_path)
    root = tree.getroot().tag


    i = 0
    for elm in (tree.findall('Data')):
        text = ET.tostring(elm)
        i += 1
        filename = "%d"%i+"_of_%s"%file_name+".xml"
        with open(filepath\\%s'%filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n")
            f.write(("<"+ "%s"%root+">"))
            f.write(text)
            f.write(("</"+ "%s"%root+">"))
            f.close()
```

Number of files to be formed is not two, it depends on the size of the source xml document, in explanation i have given a random count as 2. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a counter and check when to go to the next file:

```
i = 0
per_file = 5 # number of data per xml-file
file_counter = 1
filename = "%d"%file_counter+"_of_%s"%file_name+".xml"
f = open('C:\\Users\\kmjn026\\Desktop\\Data_MLT\\%s'%filename, 'wb')

for elm in (tree.findall('Document')):
    text = ET.tostring(elm)

    if i % per_file == 0 and i > 0:
        file_counter += 1
        f.write(("</"+ "%s"%root+">"))
        f.close()
        filename = "%d"%file_counter+"_of_%s"%file_name+".xml"
        f = open('C:\\Users\\kmjn026\\Desktop\\Data_MLT\\%s'%filename, 'wb')
        f.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n")
        f.write(("<"+ "%s"%root+">"))


    f.write(text)
    i += 1

f.write(("</"+ "%s"%root+">"))
f.close()
```